# Освободить файл от процесса

Tags: c#, wpf, файлы

У меня есть круг и его заливка это картинка которая в папке `\Resources\Images\`. При нажатии на нее пользователь может выбрать другую, которая будет на месте старой находиться и она тоже переноситься в папку где старая картинка. Но после "обновления" картинки, старая нам больше не нужна, и её нужно удалить. генерируется исключение

> System.IO.IOException: "Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "...\Resources\Images\avatar.jpg", так как этот файл используется другим процессом."

Как освободить этот файл для его дальнейшего удаления. Вот код сейчас:

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
{
    Filter = "Image Files|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;"
};
openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
string PhotoPath = openFileDialog.FileName;
if (PhotoPath != "")
{
    string fileName = PhotoPath.Split('\\').Last();
    string avatarPath = $@"Resources\Images\avatar.{fileName.Split('.').Last()}";
    if (File.Exists(avatarPath))
        File.Delete(avatarPath);
    File.Copy(PhotoPath, avatarPath);
    user.LinkToPhoto = avatarPath;
    var img = new BitmapImage(new Uri($"{user.LinkToPhoto}", UriKind.Relative));
    User_Avatar.Fill = new ImageBrush(img);
}
```

Comment: `OpenFileDialog` вызовите `Dispose` до удаления файла, только не забудьте скопировать путь к файлу.

Comment: Загружайте картинку в память как массив байт и закрывайте файл, потом формируйте уже ImageSource из байтового массива

Comment: @LLENN у OpenFileDialog нету метода Dispose

Comment: @SeeSharp: Возможно, но тс не указал какой из использует, стоит посмотреть здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @LLENN у меня `using Microsoft.Win32`;

Comment: @АндрейNOP а вот у меня в строке user.LinkToPhoto = avatarPath; я заношу строку в экземпляр класса а потом в json. С массивом байтов никаких проблем не будет? Если нет можно в ответ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам следует ознакомиться со стандартной библиотекой .Net:

```
string fileName = PhotoPath.Split('\\').Last();
// ===>
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(PhotoPath);

fileName.Split('.').Last()
// ===>
Path.GetExtension(fileName)

if (File.Exists(avatarPath))
    File.Delete(avatarPath);
File.Copy(PhotoPath, avatarPath);
// ===>
File.Copy(PhotoPath, avatarPath, overwrite: true);
```

Далее, используйте следующий метод для неблокирующей загрузки ImageSource:

```
public static ImageSource NonBlockingLoad(string path)
{
    var image = new BitmapImage();
    image.BeginInit();
    image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    image.UriSource = new Uri(path);
    image.EndInit();
    // На случай, если захотите загружать картинки фоново,
    //  а это надо сделать, т.к. пользователь может указать
    //  путь к медленному устройству или сетевой путь
    image.Freeze();
    return image;
}
```

Ну и, наконец, если вы используете для хранения настроек пользователя локальную БД или нечто подобное, может иметь смысл изменить разрешение картинки (зачем вам FullHD аватарки?) и сохранить картинку прямо в это хранилище в виде массива байтов (или в формате вроде base64), тогда можно будет использовать метод показанный в этом ответе: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9564425/6766879