# Считывание изображений без блокировки на жестком диске

Tags: c#, wpf

В элементе `Image` свойству `Source` присваивается путь к изображению. Следовательно, при попытке удалить используемое изображение я получаю сообщение системы о том, что "Действие не может быть выполнено так как этот файл открыт в ...". Как считать изображение в саму программу, не блокируя файл на жестком диске?

Comment: [ассоциация](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29625691/312041), хотя где то тут оно было и на русском.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/902775/218063