# Изменение имени картинки

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть sql запрос, который меняет название рецепта через введенное значение в texbox.
Картинка привязывается к имени в textbox

```
var directory = FilePath.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            Firstimage2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(FilePath.Combine(directory, "images/" + vivodnamerecept.Text + ".png")));
```

**НО** я ведь меняю название рецепта,а картинка остается с прежним именем.
Мне нужно чтобы если я изменил текст в textbox (напр Кулич на Куличи) и нажал на кнопку то у картинки должно изменится имя (Куличи.png)

Как это сделать?

Comment: `File.Move(...)`

Comment: @Kir_Antipov это да,но у меня же связанно с именем компонента.Я понятия не имею как это сделать

Comment: Ну так повесьте обработчик на изменение текста. Вам известно старое название (текущее) и новое. Все. `File.Move`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что при таком способе создания BitmapImage исходный файл открывается монопольно и остается открытым так неопределенное время (видимо, пока его не съест сборщик мусора), так как метода закрытия источника у этого класса нет. Вам нужно вместо этого реализовать загрузку изображения в промежуточный буфер в памяти, тогда вы сможете перемещать его как угодно. Например, это можно реализовать так:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"        
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="600">

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="60" Margin="20,20,170,20"
                 x:Name="tbFilename"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Button Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="60" Margin="20,20,20,20" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Click="Save_Click"
                IsEnabled="{Binding Path=HasChanges}"/>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="226" Margin="20,100,20,20" 
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
               Source="{Binding Path=Image}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ImageFile imagefile;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            directory = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, "images");            
            imagefile = new ImageFile(directory, "test");
            this.DataContext = imagefile;
        }     

        private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            imagefile.Save();
        }        
    }

    public class ImageFile: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string dir;
        string source_name;
        BitmapImage img;
        string new_name;

        static BitmapImage LoadImage(string path)
        {
            byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data);
            BitmapImage im = new BitmapImage();
            im.BeginInit();
            im.StreamSource = ms;
            im.EndInit();
            return im;
        }

        public ImageFile(string d,string name)
        {
            dir = d;
            source_name = name;
            var source_path = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, source_name+".png");
            img = LoadImage(source_path);
            new_name = name;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return new_name; }
            set
            {
                new_name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
                OnPropertyChanged("HasChanges");
            }
        }

        public ImageSource Image
        {
            get { return img; }
        }

        public bool HasChanges
        {
            get { return new_name != source_name; }
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            if (new_name != source_name)
            {                
                var source_path = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, source_name + ".png");
                var dest_path = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, new_name + ".png");

                System.IO.File.Move(source_path, dest_path);
                source_name = new_name;                
                OnPropertyChanged("HasChanges");

            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Для неблокирующей загрузки достаточно указать `im.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;`, читать в память отдельно не требуется: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/902775/218063