# Асинхронная загрузка изображений wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, асинхронность

Есть ListView, каждый из элементов которого которого содержит изображение, подгружаемое с сайта

```
<StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
   <Image Source="{Binding Path=AsyncProperty, IsAsync=True}" Width="30" Height="30"></Image>
   <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource BodyRegularTextStyle}" Content="{Binding Name}"></Label>
   <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource DescriptionTextStyle}" Content="{Binding Path}"></Label>
</StackPanel>
```

```
private ImageSource asyncProperty;
public ImageSource AsyncProperty 
{
   get 
   {
      if (asyncProperty == null)
         LoadImage("https://www.google.com/favicon.ico");

         return asyncProperty;
      } 

      set
      {
         LoadImage("https://www.google.com/favicon.ico");
      }
   }

   private async void LoadImage(string url)
   {
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

      try
      {
         BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
         img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
         img.BeginInit();
         img.StreamSource = await client.GetStreamAsync(url);
         img.EndInit();
         AsyncProperty = img;
      }
      сatch (HttpRequestException)
      {
                
      }
}
```

Однако, при исполнении выдает ошибку

```
System.InvalidOperationException: "Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток."
```

Как можно переписать всё это дело? Без асинхронности всё работает, но в случае если происходит ошибка при попытке получать картинку, зависает всё приложение.

Comment: Загрузка картинок в интерфейсе и так асинхронная, просто прибиндите `Source` к свойству типа `Uri`, и всё. Никакой ручной загрузки или потоков создавать не нужно. А так, вы перепутали многопоточность и асинхронность, и не показали, где там у вас `Task.Run()`. В общем, перемудрили. А еще у вас бесконечная рекурсия. `LoadImage`, который вызывает сеттер свойства, который вызывает `LoadImage`.

Comment: Сделайте `img.Freeze();` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/902775/218063

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю, можно справиться с проблемой проще. Вам не нужно вручную загружать картинку, фреймворк сделает это в фоне за вас. Вот пример:

XAML:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Uri}"/>
```

VM:

```
class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string uri;
    public string Uri
    {
        get => uri;
        set
        {
            uri = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Uri)));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Вот полный пример:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Test" Height="200" Width="200">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Click="Go">Go</Button>
        <Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="{Binding Uri}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new VM();
    }

    void Go(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = (VM)DataContext;
        vm.Uri = "https://deelay.me/1000/https://www.google.com/favicon.ico";
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: простая анимашка по имени Наташка]

---

Мне казалось, что нужно использовать атрибут `IsAsync=true` у Binding, но, как как выяснилось в результате обсуждения с @aepot в комментариях, асинхронная загрузка работает и без этого.

Comment: @aepot: `IsAsync` ещё и производит доступ к binding source в фоновом потоке (что может быть важно).